# How to use standard c++ libraries in xcode?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, objective-c++

I have a new empty xcode project. It gives me "No such file or directory" compile error when I try to import some c++ libraries such as `<iostream>`, `<string>`, and `<map>`

What do I have to do to import c++ libraries into xcode for so I can call their functions in objective-c?

Comment: how about, click on the template Xcode offers you :P

Comment: You can't call C++ libraries in Objective-C. You can call them in Objective-C++...

Answer (score 3):

If you are just trying to write C++ code in Xcode instead of calling C++ libraries in your objectiveC project you can create a C++ project. I just created a new project using the "Command Line Tool" template and selected C++ as the language.

I could then add the following lines without the compiler complaining.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
```

To use items from the std c++ libraries you prefix them with std::

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";

    return 0;
}
```

I was actually searching stack overflow for the reason std:: is necessary in Xcode...

Comment: at the top of your C++ file, simply add: using namespace std; and that should make it so that you do not need to use std:: on every file.